# flutter in app - flutter_inapp_purchase - IOS App Store reject - Performance: App Completeness

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

I have tried to use this for in app purchase.
https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_inapp_purchase
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase

here is how I implemented in app, non-consumable. It works for Android but for IOS I am not sure.
(I put my code here https://gist.github.com/axilaris/2b186c7a4073671128e8cacc09dfc384) but to summarize it below:

initialization part:

```
- initInAppPlatformState()
- _getProduct()
```

purchase part:

```
- _requestPurchase(product id)
```

(do I need to end a purchase transaction, not sure, I didnt implement finishTransactionIOS, is this needed ??)

somehow its strange, _getProduct returns title and description empty but the localizedPrice has a price.

```
flutter: productId: example_pro_inapp, price: 7.9, currency: MYR, localizedPrice: RM 7.90, title: , description: , introductoryPrice: , introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS: , subscriptionPeriodNumberIOS: 0, subscriptionPeriodUnitIOS: DAY, introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS: , introductoryPriceNumberOfPeriodsIOS: , introductoryPriceSubscriptionPeriodIOS: , subscriptionPeriodAndroid: null, introductoryPriceCyclesAndroid: null, introductoryPricePeriodAndroid: null, freeTrialPeriodAndroid: null, iconUrl: null, originalJson: null, originalPrice: null,
```

Here is the rejection description from AppStore.

```
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness


We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 13.5.1 on Wi-Fi.

The in-app purchase product loads indefinitely.

Next Steps

When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.

Resources

You can learn more about testing in-app purchase products in your development sandbox environment in App Store Connect Developer Help.

For more information on receipt validation, please see What url should I use to verify my receipt? in the In-App Purchase FAQ.

Learn how to generate a receipt validation code in App Store Connect Developer Help.
```

Do I need to call something at the end of the purchase. What steps is not correct in the workflow ? Thanks. Would like this to be approved in the AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

the way to solve this is go back to the in app purchase under itunesconnect.

just change the content abit, say the description and save it.

And then it works.

Comment: Wow, so lame on Apple's part. My two purchases had shown "Developer Action Needed" for some reason, although I couldn't tell why. After editing them, as suggested here, they changed to "Waiting for Review". Now my app can fetch them.